# lxml doesn't respect css styling when retrieving text from elements

Tags: python, css, selenium, google-chrome, lxml

I'm testing `selenium + chrome` vs `requests + lxml` for some scraping purposes. I'm interested in getting some texts.

When using `selenium + chrome`, I can do:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
return element.text.strip()
```

which will return me the text of the element that is matched by the `xpath` selector. The text will appear as it appears on the website, meaning that if the test itself is in lowercase, but it has a `text-transform: uppercase`, the output of that piece of code will be an uppercase text.

If I do the same with lxml, as follows:

```
elements = self.get_xpath_elements(xpath)
text = ''.join(elements[0].itertext()).strip()
```

it will return the text as it appears in the HTML, without taking into account the styling of the text.

Is there a way I can make lxml behave the same way as selenium + chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - it depends. What you see in the selenium case is the html, at its form after processing from a browser. And their main purpose (apart from visualizing content, for us, the mere human beings :)) is to parse html, css and js, and apply the latter two on the former. Thus getting to a result that is with their (JS and CSS'es) ruleset applied and effective (e.g. the small letters, in your example).

lxml, or any other XML parsing libraries don't do that - they parse the XML/HTML *in isolation*, they don't know (or care) for modifying systems like css (they care about XSLT, but that's a very different topic). Thus the outcome you see there is the HTML as it was written, in its "vanilla" form, any css rules it references not be applied.

---

I am saying "it depends", because you can load in lxml (or any other parser) the HTML as the browser has rendered/manipulated it. It is accessible to you in the [`self.driver.page_source`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) webdriver object's attribute.

It holds the html in the same form you'll see in "inspect element" view of a browser - with any JS and CSS structure (and content) manipulations. Yet, I don't think *precisely this case* - the lower case of the text, will be applied; I think it's in the rendering phase - e.g. the value is "as is" in the source, but the browser visualizes it differently. Regretfully I'm not in front of a computer to try it out myself.

---

The other approach I'd recommend for you is to try this library - [requests-html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/). It is a variation of the `requests` one, focused on HTML parsing (khm, just - look at its name :D). It supports javascript - and as "side effect" CSS - parsing of the raw HTML, and might do the trick for you.
The later is accomplished through the [`response_object.html.render()`](http://html.python-requests.org/#javascript-support)

Comment: Oh, how bad :( . About `request-html`, that's just headless chrome wrapped by another library. I want to avoid having to use an entire web browser, so that's a no-no for my use case.

Comment: Understood; something has to parse the js and css for you though, so it's the same shape as in the browser. Consider what if the page is using frameset - parsing just the main page you'll end up with _very_ limited content as compared to what is actually included (in browser/parser). If the chromium in that lib is not your poison of choice, then there's phantomjs - the development on it has stopped, but it's still fully usable. And yes, I do realize I'm pushing you to a browser based solution :)

Comment: Actually, my problem is not the browser per-se, but the amount of resources/time is takes. I'm dealing with a considerable amount of data to scrap (in the tens of millions range). A headless browser of any type will get the job done by the year 2373 :D